# PDE:add menu contributions only when text are selected in the editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to contribute to the popup menu **only when** some string or code are highlighted in the editor. (Yes, this quite resembles the Eclipse's built-in "Surround With" popup menu : that menu contribution only appears when some code are selected).

I tried this but not working.

```
<objectContribution
    adaptable="true"
    id="org.mydomain.Action"
    objectClass="org.eclipse.jface.text.TextSelection">
 <action
       class="org.mydomain.Action"
       enablesFor="1"
       icon="icon/icon_16.png"
       id="org.mydomain.Action"
       label="Menu..."
       menubarPath="additions">
 </action>
</objectContribution>
```

Haved searching the [wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions) and [help doc](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_cmd_menus.htm) but not finding some clues.

Comment: The 'Surround With' menu seems to be done using an override of `AbstractTextEditor.editorContextMenuAboutToShow` in the Java editor rather than a definition in the plugin.xml. This makes it much easier to check the text selection. Is this your own editor where you can do the same?

Answer (score 0):

The text selection is not an object in the sense of the object contribution model. The editor or the document in the editor are objects to which you can contribute.

To make your contribution appear dynamically instead of always, define an additional "visibility" tag for that contribution and then use a [PropertyTester](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Command_Core_Expressions#Property_Testers) inside the visibility tag to check if there is a non empty text selection (or what else you need).